# Prevent Wake-on-LAN when other devices wake from sleep or get connected to power

Tags: macos, network, sleep-wake

#### TL;DR

Waking OS X computer `A` on the network, wakes OS X computer `B`. Plugging in an iOS device to charge, wakes `B` too. Prevent this.

#### Problem

I keep my iMac in my bedroom, and just before I'm about to go to sleep I use my MacBook Pro for a while. I also connect my iPhone to the lightning connector to charge it over the night.

Both opening the MacBook Pro from sleep, *and* putting the iPhone to charge, has the incredibly annoying behavior of waking my iMac from sleep mode. So even if I've set the iMac to sleep, if I open the lid on my MacBook or plug in the phone, my iMac wakes, and its loud fans are disturbing. I've set my iMac to sleep automatically after 30 minutes, so I always have to go up and make it go to sleep again.

Why does the iMac exhibit this behavior? How do I stop it?

I think that when an iPhone gets connected to a charger, it wakes the iMac to Wi-fi sync to iTunes. Similarly, it may be that because I have my MacBook connected to a shared iTunes library on my iMac, that might be waking the iMac – but I'm not sure yet.

---

*Note*: Disabling *Wake for Wi-Fi network access* under *Settings > Energy Saver* does ***not*** prevent this behavior, from what I have gathered.

---

#### Temporary solution

If there is anyone else having this problem, this is the [quick-fix solution (SSH/VNC)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245284/can-i-remotely-force-a-locked-mac-to-sleep-or-shutdown) I am using at the moment. There are VNC apps for iOS, and in OS X there is the native `Screen Sharing` application or third-party alternatives, or the plain old `Terminal` for remote control.

Comment: If the iMac is connected via wifi, try going into `Settings --> Energy Saver` and uncheck *Wake for WiFi Network Access*.  See if that helps.

Comment: @fbara Sure, but wouldn't that also prevent me from WOL when I really do need it?

Comment: Yes, but I think that's your problem.  Plugging in your iPhone or opening your Mac is waking-up any shared service or connections causing your iMac to wake up.

Comment: Disabling *Wake for WiFi Network Access* does not prevent this issue from occurring, strangely.

Comment: What happens if you set your phone to not sync by wifi?  That is a different setting than don't wake for wifi.

Comment: @Harper That would probably prevent the problem on iPhone → Mac. But still I'm not sure why Mac → Mac wakes from sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Under Device Backups, in iTunes 12.4.1 Preferences, there is a checkbox "Prevent iPods,iPhone & iPads from syncing automatically". That should help.

Answer (score -1):

Disable "itunes agent" at login items

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions