# Can I remotely force a locked Mac to sleep or shutdown?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, remote-desktop, shutdown, remote-control

Is there any way to remotely make a Mac which is powered on – but locked – to go to sleep and/or shut down? If so, how?

E.g. can I use another *Mac B* to login via screen sharing to *Mac A* even if it's locked, and shut it down? Or can I use some other tool, like a remote Alfred script that can execute in the background even if the target computer is locked?

For this question, we are assuming that I am an administrator and have the login details to the target computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a user on a remote computer to shut down another computer whether it's a Mac or a PC, they have to have access to it first.

Whether you are using screen sharing or doing this via terminal, regardless of the computer's state (locked or unlocked), **if the user has access and the requisite privilege** , they can log in and initiate a shutdown.

It's very important to recognize that to shutdown a Mac, you don't ***need*** another Mac.  You can do it from Windows, FreeBSD, or Linux.

---

#### In terminal

Using an [SSH client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) (Terminal on a OS X) you would log into the remote machine with username/password and machine IP/DNS Name

```
ssh username@foo.bar
Password:
```

If you have the appropriate credentials, you would issue the command

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

You could issue these commands regardless if the system was locked or not, even if someone was logged in and working at the time.

#### Screen Sharing

By using another Mac and it's screen sharing capability or via [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), you could easily connect to the remote screen, and shutdown the machine even from the lock screen (notice the bottom icons):

[image]